# What does getting coefficients to unexpected direction in logistic regression signify?

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients

I'm starting to create a model for modelling the occurrence of skin cancer in patients and the patients have many available variables that may correlate to getting skin cancer (that's what I'm studying).

First I'm building a very simple model just to test some of the variables:

```
fit1 <- glm(cancer ~ trt, family = binomial, data = dta)
```

where $trt$ is a categorical variable taking values $0$ and $1$ and it signifies whether the patient has taken beta carotene supplement ($1$) or not ($0$, plasebo medicine). One expects that beta carotene should lower the risk of getting cancer, since that's what the study is essentially about.

However, the model produces the model:

$$cancer = 0.165659 + 0.5587886 \cdot trt $$

(also these coefficients are after taking `invlogit()`)

So this suggests that taking beta carotene increases the likelihood to get skin cancer by 55.87%. So this is opposite of what I expect.

Is this a problem with the model being too simple or what's wrong?

---

However, [another post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/241170/78575) suggests that I may have been computing the `invlogit()` of the coefficients wrongly. What I should perhaps do is calculate

$$-1.6167107 +  0.2362472 * 1$$

in logit-domain and then invlogit this sum

```
> invlogit(-1.380464)
[1] 0.2009345
```

so this says that if taking beta carotene then a patient has 20% risk of getting skin cancer. And

```
> invlogit(-1.6167107)
[1] 0.165659
```

i.e. 16% chance if not taking beta carotene.

Are these more reasonable?

---

As suggested in the comments, I've plotted:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you plot the distribution of beta carotene intake for those with cancer and without and compare the distributions?  I imagine you'll see essentially what the model is telling you but it doesn't hurt look, and at least this would encourage you to focus on the data rather than the model.  Could it be that those who have skin cancer are taking more beta carotene as a treatment?

Comment: This doesn't mean a 56% increase. Rather, the log-odds increases by 0.56.

Comment: Also, if both values are categorical, logistic regression could be overkill. Try running `table(dta$cancer,dta$trt)` which will be more informative than the plots you have shown (which are not actually distributions).

Comment: @jwimberley How do I plot their distributions then?

Comment: `hist(dta$cancer)` and `hist(dta$trt)` will produce the distributions.

Comment: @dsaxton Done. So I think the plot are showing that in the cancer group, there are more of those that have used beta carotene, rather than those that haven't. But since those having cancer is a smaller group than those not having, then do the plots really signify that the likelihood of getting cancer by eating beta carotene should increase like that?

Comment: Parallel boxplots would be a good way of comparing the distributions of beta carotene intake.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight I'm given that this is a "longitudinal study". And every patient belongs to a "risk group", having had skin cancer earlier.

Comment: @dsaxtor boxplot(de$trt) for de when patient has cancer or hasn't or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing 20% risk under treatment and 16% risk under no treatment. That's plausible. The calculation is possibly a minor issue.

Note that the canonical parameter from a logistic model is the odds ratio. You just exponentiate (not inverse logit transform) the coefficient to get the odds ratio. That is

$$exp(0.2362472) \approx 1.3$$ or that treatment is associated with 1.3 times the odds under no treatment. You can confirm this with your probabilities

$$odds(trt)/odds(no~ trt) = (0.2/(1-0.2))/(.16/(1-.16)) \approx 1.3$$

The larger issue is that you don't indicate whether or not this is a clinical trial of the effect of treatment. In the case that patients choose their own treatment, there may be factors that are associated with that choice that are also associated with the outcome. For example, if really pale individuals were more likely to choose treatment, you might observe an odds ratio > 1 even if treatment had no effect (or a beneficial effect) on skin cancer. This is referred to as confounding.

Another issue is sample size. In a small population, you are more likely to see extreme or unexpected results simply because it is easy for one or two unusual individuals to influence the results (more exactly, you are likely to have a non-representative sample). This influences statistical precision. If you have an odds ratio of 1.3 with confidence intervals that span from 0.1 to 10, then you may be just seeing statistical 'noise.'

Comment: Does looking at the odds ratio correspond of just comparing $0.20/0.16 = 1.25 ≈ 1.3$? I.e. that from "base level" (0.16, no treatment) it's 30% more likely to get cancer with treatment.

Comment: That is the risk ratio: $Pr(Y|trt)/Pr(Y|no trt)$ The risk ratio and the odds ratio will be approximately equal when the risk is low. You should be able to get answers closer to each other if you calculate the probabilities to further decimal places.

Comment: I personally think the risk difference 0.2-0.16 =0.04 is the most interesting effect measure, but this is more about personal preference than anything else.

Comment: However, I still don't understand why I'm seeing treatment creating more risk for cancer. I mean, what's the reason for this? Too less variables, noise in data, ...?

Comment: That's not something I, or anyone, can answer definitively. You may have confounding. I would start by looking at other variables associated with both the outcome and the treatment, and I would also get confidence intervals around the odds ratios.

Comment: Wonder if the numbers I got correlate with the histograms though? Specifically this second pic (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyYFN.png), since in the "no cancer" one the number of beta carotene and plasebo takers seem to be equal. The second histogram shows that there are more beta carotene takers that got cancer than those that didn't.

Comment: And judging by this. I should probably look at more variables in order to see the correct trends. Using just $trt$ might be "by chance" giving these contradicting coefficient values.

Comment: How does one infer the odds ratio? Like what does odds ratio 1.3 mean?